# Use Pandas to concat csv's into another folder

Tags: python, pandas

A coworker wrote this to combine csv files that are batch downloads of a DB table:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
folder_path = r'C:\_batches'

files = [os.path.join(folder_path, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path)]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, file)) for file in files])
df.to_csv('combo_csv.csv', index=None)
```

The issue I have is that it's 60gb of data and climbing, so I have to combine the files into another drive where there's space.
I modified like this, just spitballing, but it doesn't work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
folder_path_input = r'C:\_batches'
folder_path_output = r'D:\_batches_Concat'

files = [os.path.join(folder_path_input, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path_input)]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path_output, file)) for file in files])
df.to_csv('batch_1.csv', index=None)
```

How can I modify the code to concat to another folder?

Comment: I think you mean `df.to_csv(r'D:\_batches_Concat\combo_csv.csv', index=None)` to write the final dataframe to other disk

Comment: @AndrejKesely didn't work.  I thought since `df` contained output path then that would do the trick

Comment: @OCa because I'm very new to Python and don't know how to troubleshoot yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, file)) for file in files])
```

This line is your code is causing the issue because you are concatenating the path of the input folder and the output folder when reading the csv's, This results in in pandas trying to read an invalid file path.

```
import pandas as pd
folder_path_input = r'C:\_batches'
folder_path_output = r'D:\_batches_Concat'

files = [os.path.join(folder_path_input, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path_input)]

#reads and combines all files found in input folder
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])

# writes to a file in the output folder
df.to_csv(os.path.join(folder_path_input,'batch_1.csv'), index=None)
```

This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: `import os` is missing because of code block formatting, suggest an edit.  I can't without changing at least 6 characters.